# iOS : video not playing on homepage, only on other page

Tags: ios, html5-video

I have a same layout on homepage and test page.  **The problem appears only on iOS**: the video plays on the test page, **but not on the homepage**. Nothing in the console. Same html, same js, same css, same video file, same poster, etc...

Any idea ?
Cheerz

Comment: please show us a sample that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I have two running pages : [homepage](https://depotax.com) &  [page](https://depotax.com/test)...  Or did you want to see code ?

Comment: fwiw the video on the test page doesn't autoplay for me on Chrome/macOS (even though the asset does load and play if accessed directly). A quick test page that just includes the video tag does work. my guess would be something else in the wordpress template is blocking the autoplay

Comment: @Offbeatmammal  There was a difference between the pages for hours during my tests, and i was checking to empty cache... but maybe not the last time in touched the code.   So it ticked me :  What latest change have i made for u not to see the difference ?   ... And it led to the answer below.   Thank you very much for you undirect help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my bad...  there was a little CSS difference between the two pages : the home page had a `position: fixed` element as deep parent.

So the lesson is :  **no** `position: fixed` on (deep) parent of the `<video>` tag if iOS is needed.